# different time for view and table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody tell me why there are difference between this:

1)

view2 -> view1 -> remoute_server_table

select * from view2 - needs 8 min

2)

view2 -> table1 -> remoute_server_table

select * from view2 - needs 10 sec

Everything is the same on both variants:

- view2 has 5 joins
- remoute_server_table is the same

Difference is in using table1 or view1:

view1:

```
CREATE VIEW view1
AS
SELECT ...
FROM remoute_server_table as o
WHERE CAST(o.Период as Date) >= DATEADD(d,-1, CAST(getdate() as Date))
```

table1:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table1;
GO


INSERT table1 (...)
SELECT ...
FROME remoute_server_table as loc
WHERE CAST(loc.Период as Date) >= DATEADD(d,-1, CAST(getdate() as Date))
GO
```

SO, table1 ~ view1 by select clause and data.

Edit1: Execution plans are different. There are no indexes for table1 and for view1

Comment: Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: Yes, I did, but could not manage to understand where is the problem. Execution plans are diffrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you fill `table1`, do you fill it before doing a select on it?

When you use the solution with `view1` it retrieves the data from the remote server at execution time, this most likely causes the delay.

If you fill `table1` before executing the select statement then you select the data from the local server without needing to create a connection to the remote server.

Comment: Yes. I fill table1 before selecting from view2. 
So, variant 1 will always suffer from connection to remoute serve?

Comment: I thought that view1 will be executed and will be stored in RAM or in temp_table... Execution plan shows that RemouteQuery cost 24%

Comment: Yes. You could create a SQL Agent Job that fills the table every hour or what suits your requirements, this is how I usually do it. However, if you do not want your table to be empty for 8 minutes you could create an extra "staging area" table where you insert data into before inserting them into the actual table.

Comment: Yes. I thought about such plan.
The issue to use the variant with view1 was to make my SSAS cube's partition be in ROLAP mode and take data from view2 - so it will be uptodate to remoute_server_table.
So, it seems to be only one variant to do this - use sql-jod =(